# powershell studio 2015 validation

Tags: powershell

I have downloaded "Validation Sample Form" from this site at this url[Sample Validation Form](https://www.sapien.com/blog/2011/09/23/primalforms-2011-validating-the-form-part-4/)

The Authors form runs with validation correctly. Note the Red Information Button to the left of the first name textbox when I tab out of that text box. All of the other validations work as well. Note I am running the left most form tab SampleValidation. See Picture Below[image: Sample Validation]

Now I have created the exact same form and named it Sample1Validation. Everthing is the same from the size of the form to all the control locatons and all property settings on the form. I only named mine Sample1Validation to show the difference. So all the code behind should be exactly the same except for this 1 event handler:

```js
$formValidation1Sample_FormClosing = [System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler]{
  #Event Argument: $_ = [System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs]
  #Validate only on OK Button
  if ($formValidation1Sample.DialogResult -eq "OK")
  {
   #Validate the Child Control and Cancel if any fail
   $_.Cancel = -not $formValidation1Sample.ValidateChildren()
  }
 }
```

[image: Sample1 Validation]

What could be causing this? I have created several forms with different scenario's and nothing works that I create. The validation code is very simple to understand and I think I understand it quite well but it is just not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. You need to manually assign the Validating event to the control as it is not being done automatically.
Select the control, change the properties view (on the right dock) to events. Under focus you will find Validating, double click it.

Your code for the Textbox should look like this (it is not being displayed in powershell studio):

```
<Object type="System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" name="textbox1" children="Controls">
  <Property name="Location">74, 58</Property>
  <Property name="Name">textbox1</Property>
  <Property name="Size">100, 20</Property>
  <Property name="TabIndex">0</Property>
  <Event name="Validating">textbox1_Validating</Event>
</Object>
```